# Python Flask: Retrieving the id from a database (converting tuple into int)

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask

I have written a Flask App which can access a mysql database running in a Dockerfile with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tasksdb (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    task VARCHAR(20),
    is_completed BOOLEAN,
    notify VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I need to return the id of the task which was last created. Thus, I would like to retrieve the id from the database. I have tried several variants but none of them worked:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM tasksdb WHERE task="%s"', [task])
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Output: `()`

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasksdb")
```

Output: `((1,),)`, `((2,),)` etc for each time running the command.

However, I am confused since the database shows this, when running the following in the Docker bash shell:

```
SELECT * from tasksdb;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Nonetheless, I try to get the 1,2 etc from the output so that my function can return this:

The problem is that 
`string_id=str(cursor.fetchall())` leads to output `()`. Thus, I have no idea how to access the middle part.

`res = int(''.join(map(str, cursor.fetchall())))` leads to 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

`res=cursor.fetchall()[0]`
leads to: IndexError: `tuple index out of range`

Could you help me how I could get the id?

Additionally, I am wondering why the id always starts again at 1 when restarting the flask application and running the test but not restarting the mysql container. I would expect the container and database to create the tasks with a new id even after restarting.

Here is my full code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import json
import MySQLdb
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

cursor = None

def get_db_connection():
    global cursor
    if not cursor:
        db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "DockerPasswort!", "demo", port=3306)
        cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor

# Create a new task
@app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    cursor = get_db_connection()
    data = request.get_json()
    if "title" not in data:
        return bulkadd(data)
    is_completed=False
    if "is_completed" in data:
        is_completed=data["is_completed"]
    notify=""
    if "notify" in data:
        notify=data["notify"]
    task = data["title"]
    sql='INSERT INTO tasksdb (task, is_completed, notify) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
    cursor.execute(sql, [task, is_completed, notify])
    #Insert any of the attempts to obtain the id here and return it.
    return "True"
```

Thank you for your help!

-------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------
I just added a task directly in mysql and executed this:

```
SELECT * from tasksdb;
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+  
| id | task          | is_completed | notify                      |  
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+  
| 22 | My First Task |            0 | test@berkeley.edu |  
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+  
1 row in set
```

The fact that id is 22 convinces me that the requests earlier were stored. However, I do not understand why only this one row is returned? Should all former requests not be saved as well?

Comment: Use SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM tasksdb;  to get the max id but i still don't get what you are searching for

Comment: see http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-get-the-maximum-value-of-a-column-MySQL-table-Python.php and instead of Float you use int.